# Sorting A Random Valued Array Ascendingly by the Value

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I am new to C++, I have a problem with sorting an array that has random value generated by rand() function.
The array length is 100 and the value was filled by a random number from 0 to 9 (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).

I have already succeed on determining the array's value, but still failed when I want to sort the array based on it's value ascendingly. By this, it means that when I print the array value, it may not be sorted by it's index, but by it's value.

Like this:

X[10]=0;

X[1]=1;

X[60]=2; ... etc until X[99]=...

Here is code to determine the value and sort it, what I have wrong here? Please help..

```
int length= 100;
X = new int[length];

int i;
int j;
int temp;


//determining the array value
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    X[i] = rand() % 10;
}

//sorting
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < length; j++) {

        if (X[i] < X[j]) {
            temp = X[j];
            X[j] = X[i];
            X[i] = temp;
        }

    }
}

//print the array
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    cout << "X[" << i << "] = " << X[i] << "\n";
    Sleep(10);
}
```

Code above won't print the sorted by value, it printed the array sorted by it's index ascendingly, not by it's value like what I want above.

Please hand me solution to this,

Thanks in advance

Comment: If this is an assignment or there is a good reason for you to write your own sorting, you should mention that in the question. Otherwise, use `std::sort`.

Comment: @juanchopanza it is not an assignment, it's just I want to learn C++ sorting on array my self, but I got this problem. I'm going to have an edit of the question

Comment: Put the values into the array *before* you start sorting it.

Comment: I've done it @molbdnilo in that first looping of my code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to initialize and sort the array in the same loop.

-First initialize the array:

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    X[i] = rand() % 10;
}
```

-Then sort the array: (Below sorting method is insertion sort, if you want to speed the process you can use counting sort since the array only contains numbers.)

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
for (j = i+1; j < length; j++) {
    if (X[i] > X[j]) {
        temp = X[j];
        X[j] = X[i];
        X[i] = temp;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Yes that what I've done, exactly by the code you written here. So, do you have any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: @codelop Look closely at his second loop and `if` statement.

Comment: I just parted your loop into 2 different parts, which was the main problem. You were trying to do these two steps in just one.

Comment: have tried it but still it printed the same result as before, the printed one looks X[0] until X[9] valued 0, then X[10] until X[19] valued 1, ... until X[99] = 99. What I want is the value sorted ascendingly, while the index may be printed randomly

Comment: Thank you @SinanArıyürek It actually helps me to sort the value, but it doesn't adjust the array's index. Finally I have come to a method where I use random to assign the index. I am gonna pick this answer. Thanks everyone